# Swap Space Allocation Problem

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8, gparted, swap

I have a **single 160 GB physical hard drive**. I have Windows 8.1 installed on 100 GB (Local Disk C:). I left the remaining 60 GB as unallocated space for Ubuntu installation.

Now, the problem is that when I have to assign Root, Home, Swap space on that unallocated 60 GB, I can only assign Root and Home. The remaining 20 GB is shown as **unknown space**. 
It says there can only be maximum of 4 partitions on a single drive and I have used all of them (Windows has apparently used up 2 partitions).

So, what should I do? Should I forgo the Swap space or is there any other way to get around this problem?

Please explain in layman terms if you can.

P.S : I don't want to remove Windows 8.1 from my computer but I want to dual-boot Ubuntu alongside Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those max. 4 *primary* partitions can be an *extended* partition which in turn can hold up to 16 *logical* partitions. So in total you can create up to 19 usable partitions on a drive with an MBR partition table.

If you choose “something else“ as installation type, the partition manager of the Ubuntu installer lets you choose between creating primary or logical partitions:

[image: partition creation dialogue]

The partition manager will automatically create an extended partition if necessary to accommodate a newly created logical partition. It hides the complexity of dealing with this technical detail.

**You should not forgo swap space:**

- If your computer runs out of physical main memory and has no swap space to fall back on, it will

  - start to kill user space processes¹ (and it's hard to predict which ones) to accommodate memory needs of the kernel and
  - behave erratically, because memory allocation for user space processes¹ will fail, which most applications aren't programmed to anticipate; this usually leads to crashes because these applications then try to access invalid memory addresses.
- While it's possible to have a swap file inside a file system, suspension to a swap file isn't implemented in the kernel. You pretty much need a swap partition for that.
- As I described above it's easy enough to create a swap partition if you can have up to 19 partitions on one drive – a big deal easier than dealing with the aforementioned two problems.

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Partitions

¹ A “user space process“ is what a layman may call an “application”, but the former also encompass other things like server applications and system services.

Comment: So how do I make an extended partition? I mean after creating /root space, I have only one partition left. So, are you saying I should make the partition extended? How can I do that (within Windows or during Linux installation)? Can you please provide me with a good link where I can learn to do that?

Comment: As described in my answer and the Ubuntu Community Help article you can create logical partitions for Ubuntu during its installation, of which you can have *up to 16*. The picture in my answer shows the [partition creation dialogue window](//i.stack.imgur.com/c1njj.jpg) of the partition manager of the installer with the radio buttons for the partition type at the top.

Comment: I just noticed you asked about the *extended partition* in particular and updated my answer accordingly. Short answer: You don't need to create one; the partition manager will do it for you. Other partition managers (e. g. GParted) often require you to create the extended partition manually. Read their manuals if you don't find the right controls by yourself.

Comment: Okay. I got the gist but I am still a little confused between Extended and Logical Partition. Should I assign Logical Partition for /Swap or should I create a Extended partition to solve the problem? Also, does the Linux partition manager allow me to create Extended partition while installation itself or I have to do it manually using Gparted?

Comment: Extended partitions should only be used as a wrapper for logical partitions. I feel like all the alternatives I mention are more confusing than helping you, so I'm going to do what I don't like to do: to tell people what they should do. — Just use the partition manager of the Ubuntu installer and select “logical“ as the partition type for every partition you create. Create as many partitions as you feel are necessary. The upper limit of 19 is plenty.

Comment: Okay then. I am going to assign Logical Partition for /root /home and /swap space instead of Primary partition like you said. But what I'm afraid is that creating logical partition might result in exceeding the 40GB I left aside for Ubuntu when I actually use Ubuntu.

Comment: The occupied space has nothing to do with the partition type. Using fewer partitions will not give you more space (or only negligible amounts of a few MB). 40 GB are more than enough for Ubuntu itself, a swap partition, and a home directory independently of whether each of those is located on its own partition. You cannot accidentally allocate more space to a partition than is left on its drive.

Comment: So, instead of choosing Primary for the root/home/swap space, I should choose Logical for all of them? But will I be able to allocate the desired space for each of them when I choose Logical for all three?

Comment: Yes. Make them all logical partitions. You can distribute the free space amongst them however you like regardless of their type.

Answer (score 2):

There can be only 4 *primary* partitions, but there can be many more *logical* partitions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Zhis *does* in fact answer the question, although it's a bit short on additional information...

Comment: This answer only addresses one small part of the issue and doesn't try to answer “So, what should I do? Should I forgo the Swap space or is there any other way to get around this problem?”

Comment: @DavidFoerster It's saying that the OP should make logical partitions to get around the problem. This would benefit considerably from expansion. But it addresses the entirety of the question and is a real answer. More importantly, it's not an attempt to critique or request clarification. When you see an answer you think only addresses part of the question or doesn't contain enough information, even in cases where you think it should be removed, I recommend against instructing people to post it as a comment. [*Such answers shouldn't be comments.*](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/2281)

Comment: +1 I get your point. Thanks for the explanation.